# Expressing php code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to insert html code through a php variable in javascript.  I am getting the following error below. Please can someone advise?

Error Message: "Unexpected Identifier 'Inactive'" ($option has values 'Inactive'/ 'Active')

PHP

```
$tr_active_Options = '';
$sql1 = "SELECT status FROM tr_active";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql1);
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
$option = $row['status'];

$option = '<div class="dpOtions" onclick="track.addChosenOption(\''.$option.'\', \'act_ui\')">'.$option.'</div>';

$tr_active_Options .= $option;
}


$tr_active = '<div class="drpClass"><div class="dropOptionsDiv" id="actList_ui">'.$tr_active_Options.'</div></div>';
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML = '<div id="editWrap"><?php echo $tr_active; ?></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` in your string are terminating the JavaScript string you've started with `'`.

You can safely have PHP generate a string for use in JavaScript using `json_encode`, like so:

```
document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML =
    '<div id="editWrap">' +
    <?php echo json_encode($tr_active); ?> +
    '</div>';
```

Note how the JavaScript string ends, then we use `+` to join it with the one that PHP will output (`json_encode` will handle the strings), then we `+` it with another JavaScript string after it. What the browser will see will look like this:

```
document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML =
    '<div id="editWrap">' +
    "contents of $tr_active here" +
    '</div>';
```

...which is valid.

That said: Using PHP to generate HTML with embedded JavaScript inside attributes is asking for a world of hurt. Separate those concerns! :-)